# Unable to run Scala Play app throwing com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying run a Scala Play app and got this exception:

```
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'memo'
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:152) ~[config-1.3.1.jar:na]
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:170) ~[config-1.3.1.jar:na]
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:184) ~[config-1.3.1.jar:na]
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189) ~[config-1.3.1.jar:na]
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:264) ~[config-1.3.1.jar:na]
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:270) ~[config-1.3.1.jar:na]
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:37) ~[config-1.3.1.jar:na]
at lila.common.PlayApp$.loadConfig(PlayApp.scala:24) ~[na:na]
at lila.memo.Env$.lila$memo$Env$$$anonfun$1(Env.scala:28) ~[na:na]
at lila.common.Chronometer$.sync(Chronometer.scala:56) ~[na:na]
```

I put external reference to the  configuration file such as :

```
run -Dconfig.resource=conf/base.conf
```

I am new to Scala.Tried to find out conifg-1.3.1-jar but unable to find out.Can you please suggest how to overcome this situation.

**In the base.conf there is configuration for the memo is present.

Answer (score 0):

Try without `conf/`, run -Dconfig.resource=base.conf

From Play 2.6 docs

#### [Using](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#Using--Dconfig.resource) `-Dconfig.resource`

This will search for an alternative configuration file in the application classpath (you usually provide these alternative configuration files into your application conf/ directory before packaging). Play will look into conf/ **so you don’t have to add conf/**.

> $ /path/to/bin/ -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf

#### [Using](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#Using--Dconfig.file) `-Dconfig.file`

You can also specify another local configuration file not packaged into the application artifacts:

> $ /path/to/bin/ -Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/prod.conf

If you are configuring an sbt task from Intellij you must [quote](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-pass-command-line-arguments-sbt-run) the entire command.

> "run -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf"

Comment: Add the line in wich you are using the conf and the conf itself.

Comment: You are using Intellij or the sbt console directly?

Comment: I've updated the answer, you must quote the command if you are using Intellij

Comment: problem solved.May be it was the problem with sbt. With Intellij works fine with Dconfig. Thanks.